# How do I find out gems released today (or this week)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Perl has a [CPAN's 150 most recent uploads](http://www.cpan.org/modules/01modules.mtime.html) page. Is there something similar(or close) for ruby gems? I am looking for a web page that lists the newest
additions to the ruby gems index.

Answer (score 1):

Rubygems has an API method to pull the 50 most recently updated gems. From their [API Documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-org-api/#activity-methods):

> GET - /api/v1/activity/just_updated
>
> Pulls the 50 most recently updated gems. Returns an array of the JSON or YAML representation of the gem versions.
>
> $ curl 'https://rubygems.org/api/v1/activity/just_updated.json'